# Vacation price program Python

Tags: python

I am doing a project in code academy and I have to make a program that adds up all the vacation cost (like travel, city, ...etc).  I am not sure what wrong with my code.

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return nights * 140

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    if days < 3:
        return 40 * days
    elif days >= 3 and days < 7:
        return days * 40 - 20 
    elif days >= 7:
        return days * 40 - 50

def trip_cost(city,days):
    city = plane_ride(city)
    days = rental_car_(days) + hotel_cost(nights)
    return total_cost(city + days)
```

Also, any advice on how to make my code less redundant and clean.

Comment: What is it not doing that it should do, or doing that it shouldn't?

Comment: Well, it raises an immediate `IndentationError`. If I fix that, it defines a bunch of functions that it never calls, and doesn't do anything else. So, if it's intended to do nothing at all, fix the indentation; otherwise, you need to actually do something somewhere.

Comment: oh sorry, it should add up the total cost the total cost of hotal_cost and plane_ride and rental_car_cost

Comment: Meanwhile, have you considered building a dictionary, like `city_costs = {"Charlotte": 183, "Tampa": 220, … }`, so that `plane_ride_cost(city)` can just `return city_costs[city]`?

Comment: Also, `days >= 3 and days < 7` is more readable as `3 <= days < 7`—but in this case, you don't even need that; you just need `elif days < 7`, because you already _know_ it's >=3 or you wouldn't have gotten past the first `if`. And likewise, just `else`, not `elif days >= 7` in the last branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `trip_cost` is messed up.  It never calculates `total_cost`, and tries to call a nonexistent function.  Here's my guess on what you meant:

```
def trip_cost(city, days):
    nights = days - 1
    total_cost = plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(nights)
    return total_cost
```

Comment: That's definitely _a_ big problem with the code. Given an incomplete program and no explanation, it's hard to say this is _the_ problem he came here with, but… a valiant guess at the very least.

Comment: yeah, everything works supposedly to codeacademy.  the only problem is when i try to add all the prices up.  so basically def trip_cost(city, days) and down. is the issue of my code

Comment: Thank you recursive, Night = days -1. didnt work because it basically said if you stay 0 days you cant stay negative nights.  so i made night = days.  and it work, so thank you and everyone else who helped

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is late, it's meant for those that will need help in the future.

The right script Codeacademy was most likely looking for is as follows:

```
    def trip_cost(city,days):
        totalcost=plane_ride_coast(city)+rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)
        return totalcost
```

Codeacademy assumes that the # of days the car was rented(rental_car_cost) is equal to the # of nights that were stayed(hotel_costs), because of this only two parameters were needed(city, days) and not the third(nights).

I hope this helped.