# Get user input for function

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python using codeacdemy. This was one of their excercises. Basically they had me create 4 different functions that calculated the total cost. But there was no option to ask the user to manually enter in the values. So thats what I am trying to to. The code is right upto the `return rental-car_cost` part. its just the bottom bit where I am having trouble.

```
print "this code calculates the total price of a trip, using 4 functions"

def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140*nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if (city=="Charlotte"):
        return 183

    elif(city=="Tampa"):
        return 220

    elif(city=="Pittsburgh"):
        return 222

    elif(city=="Los Angeles"):
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost=days*40

    if (days>=7):
        cost -= 50

    elif(days>=3):
        cost -=20

    return cost

def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)+ plane_ride_cost(city)+spending_money

city= raw_input("enter city name")
days= raw_input("enter number of days staying")
spending_money= raw_input("enter spendig money")
print trip_cost(city,days, spending_money)
```

this was the original code and it rune perfectly fine. All i want to do is have the user enter the values when the code it running.

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140*nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if (city=="Charlotte"):
        return 183

    elif(city=="Tampa"):
        return 220

    elif(city=="Pittsburgh"):
        return 222

    elif(city=="Los Angeles"):
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost=days*40

    if (days>=7):
        cost -= 50

    elif(days>=3):
        cost -=20

      return cost

def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)+ plane_ride_cost(city)+spending_money

print trip_cost("Los Angeles",5,600)
```

Comment: Btw I know i can just say print trip_cost("los angeles", 5, 100) and that will give me the answer. But i want to ask the user in the console without changing the code every time. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to fix your indentation.

Comment: i think my indentation is right for the original code. my code runs error free, and i know is 100% right upto return rental_car_cost(days) +hotel-cost(days)+.....

Comment: As it appeared here it was not. I've fixed it. Did you try to run the code as it was originally? As it was it would not even have compiled.

Comment: Is the problem that the code does not run or gives incorrect results?  I believe you will need to cast the output of the raw_input calls to float to get the days and spending money input.

Comment: i posted the orginal code

Comment: the origial code gives the right results, its just that i am trying to modify the ending a but so the user enters the values when the code is running and not when the code is stopped.

Comment: @user4081147 Hey check my solution that I've posted below and see if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `int(raw_input(enter number of days staying"))` or `input("enter number of days staying")` instead of `raw_input("enter number of days staying")` What happens ? You see any difference ? This is because `raw_input()` converts input data into string but it's not the same with `input()`. Find out the differences between `input()` and raw_input() and how it has changed as python has evolved. I have made some changes to the code as shown below. It runs perfectly without errors. Let me know if it helped you.

```
print "this code calculates the total price of a trip, using 4 functions"

def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140*nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if (city=="Charlotte"):
        return 183

    elif(city=="Tampa"):
        return 220

    elif(city=="Pittsburgh"):
        return 222

    elif(city=="Los Angeles"):
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost=days*40

    if (days>=7):
        cost -= 50

    elif(days>=3):
        cost -=20

    return cost

def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)+ plane_ride_cost(city)+spending_money

city= raw_input("enter city name")
days= int(raw_input("enter number of days staying"))  ##### notice here
spending_money= int(raw_input("enter spendig money")) ### and here too
print trip_cost(city,days, spending_money)
```

Instead of the above you can use the following code too.

```
################## without type casting#############
    city= raw_input("enter city name")
    days= input("enter number of days staying")  ##### notice something here
    spending_money= input("enter spendig money") ### and here 
    print trip_cost(city,days, spending_money)
```

Comment: thx so much I understand now. the code works perfectly and runs well too. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

## Equal question:

[Vacation price program Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709514/vacation-price-program-python?rq=1)

## Propose

Consider it only like some to improve this code. I think so it didn't answer your question.

I don't know what propose of Code Academy for that exercise but some way easier and cleaner is at below:

```
print "this code calculates the total price of a trip, using 4 functions"

def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    #So you can create dict and put for each city
    #Key - name of city
    #value - cost
    CITY_COST = {
        "Charlotte": 183,
        "Pittsburgh" : 222,
        "Los Angeles" : 475,
        "Tampa": "220"
    }
    #Method from dict 
    #if city doesn't exists it'll return False
    #The second param is default return if doesn't exist key into dict
    #you can change if do you want
    return CITY_COST.get(city, False)



def rental_car_cost(days):

    cost = days * 40

    if (days >= 7):
        cost -= 50

    elif(days >=3 ):
        cost -=20

    return cost

def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)+ plane_ride_cost(city)+spending_money

city= raw_input("enter city name")
days= raw_input("enter number of days staying")
spending_money= raw_input("enter spendig money")
print trip_cost(city,days, spending_money)
```

## Documentation about Dict

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: this code has the exact same problem as the code that i wrote :(. I cant figure out what i am doing wrong